# Why does this fail on some MySQL installs and not on other MySQL/MariaDB installs

Tags: mysql

FINAL: I'm closing this question because there is no way for me to reproduce the condition and trying to find a similar occurrence has proven fruitless.

A work-around using perl is being implemented to circumvent the failure that only some mysql installs are experiencing.

---

UPDATE: I've had another case and verified that this query is returning 'OFF'

```
SELECT `VARIABLE_VALUE` FROM `information_schema`.`GLOBAL_VARIABLES` WHERE `VARIABLE_NAME` LIKE 'INNODB_STRICT_MODE'
```

I'm having a hard time tracking down a query issue...

This is part of an update script that I made to install new tables and import data from old ones - if they exist. This is from a procedure that is installed, and then called, by the update script:

In this snippet, the table `bot_inventories` is created, then a check is performed to see if the old schema table exists. If it does, the old 'base' data is then copied to the new table.

The suspect query is the 'inner' if near the bottom:

```
CREATE TABLE `bot_inventories` (
    `inventories_index` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `bot_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `slot_id` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `item_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `inst_charges` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    `inst_color` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `inst_no_drop` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `inst_custom_data` TEXT NULL,
    `ornament_icon` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ornament_id_file` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ornament_hero_model` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_1` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_2` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_3` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_4` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_5` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `augment_6` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`inventories_index`),
    KEY `FK_bot_inventories_1` (`bot_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_bot_inventories_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bot_id`) REFERENCES `bot_data` (`bot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'botinventory') > 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO `bot_inventories` (
        `inventories_index`,
        `bot_id`,
        `slot_id`,
        `item_id`,
        `inst_charges`,
        `inst_color`,
        `inst_no_drop`,
        `augment_1`,
        `augment_2`,
        `augment_3`,
        `augment_4`,
        `augment_5`
    )
    SELECT
        bi.`BotInventoryID`,
        bi.`BotID`,
        bi.`SlotID`,
        bi.`ItemID`,
        bi.`charges`,
        bi.`color`,
        bi.`instnodrop`,
        bi.`augslot1`,
        bi.`augslot2`,
        bi.`augslot3`,
        bi.`augslot4`,
        bi.`augslot5`
    FROM `botinventory` bi
    INNER JOIN `bot_data` bd
    ON bi.`BotID` = bd.`bot_id`;

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'botinventory' AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'augslot6') > 0) THEN
        UPDATE `bot_inventories` bi
        INNER JOIN `botinventory` bio
        ON bi.`inventories_index` = bio.`BotInventoryID`
        SET bi.`augment_6` = bio.`augslot6`
        WHERE bi.`bot_id` = bio.`BotID`;
    END IF;

    RENAME TABLE `botinventory` TO `botinventory_old`;
END IF;
```

I have run this script myself dozens of times on both 'clean' and convertible (existing and populated `botinventory` table) databases with no problems.

The script executes properly on both MySQL v5.1.73 and MariaDB v10.0.22 (both win x86)

However, I've had two reported cases of failure surrounding the 'inner' if statement.

That check is in place to catch any 'customization' that may have been done by an admin and import their data.

The failed cases are reporting: "ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

I walked one of the admins through the manual installation of this update and found the problem to be with the 'if' query.

EDIT: It's acting like the query inside of the con check is firing off - defeating the purpose of the check itself (NULL is greater than '0'?)

(The walk-through admin is running MySQL v5.1.x as x86 on windows server 2012..the other is running MySQL v5.1.x as win (7?) x86.)

It seems to report that error when 'augslot6' does not exist - opposite behavior of what the check is in place to prevent.

I'm just not sure whether this is a syntax/methodology issue or an actual database code bug.

Searching for similar cases almost exclusively turns up results for column-entry count mis-matches, not why an if statement proves true with a false/null result...

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I am aware of what ANSI SQL code '21S01' indicates and how it could be interpreted to mean the missing `augslot6` column. But, if so, why is the 'if' query proving 'true' when it should be 'false' on some systems?

EDIT: I wasn't able to perform the failing test myself as I don't have access to these systems.